# Tibco xpath daylight saving issue

Tags: dst, tibco

Does anyone here knows how to solve the Tibco xpath daylight saving date issue.

The issue was we have one record **03/10/2013 02:00** parsed via Tibco mapping palette with following format (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm). However, it got invalid date time error with above date. It worked with all other times, e.g. 03/10/2013 01:00, 03/10/2013 03:00, just not working with anytime between 03/10/2013 02:00 ~ 03/10/2013 02:59.

The current xpath we using parse-dateTime(format, string)

So, can xpath detect the daylight saving automatically with the inbound date format (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm) and parse it?

Thanks so much.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The TIBCO function that parses dateTime does detect Day Light Saving.

I think you have two options to handle these cases in your engine.

1. Change the code to have a Java Code parse the dateTime. I am aware
   that java correctly returns the time with 1 hour added in this case.
   You should be able to do a TimeZone.getDefault() to get the server's
   default TimeZone.
2. Change the java default timezone in the TRA - java.property.user.timezone in the designer.tra I suppose.

I have not tried these. :-)

Comment: Thanks yem yem yen for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with DST, trying to parse string `2014-03-30 02:00:00` which does not exist in italian timeZone.

Since the input date was perfectly legit (intended to be in GMT+0) I solved by forcing the timezone with this code. It should work with any other timezone as long as it doesn't support DST.

```
tib:parse-dateTime("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"), concat($Start/root/dateTimeFrom, ' +0000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable daylight in deployment.yaml (kubernetes)

```yaml
- name: BW_JAVA_OPTS
  value: "-Dbw.engine.enable.memory.saving.mode=true -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m"
```